# pycharm: read from standard input in "debug" mode

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I'm debugging this script in PyCharm:

```
import sys

def read_in():
    lines = sys.stdin.readlines()
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        lines[i] = lines[i].replace('\n','')
    return lines

def main():
    lines = read_in()
    print lines

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I normally call this script using a command like `cat data.txt | python script.py` which feeds data.txt into Standard Input.

My question is how can I setup a "Run/Debug Configuration" in PyCharm which feeds data.txt into Standard Input in the same way, but which will allow me to use PyCharm's awesome debugging mode? I suspect that I need to correctly fill out the "Script Parameters" field -- but this has eluded me so far.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd just use patch to replace sys.stdin.readlines() with a Mock, with the return value you desire. Place that into a unit test, and run the unit test.

Also, see
[Reading from a file with sys.stdin in Pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21630403/reading-from-a-file-with-sys-stdin-in-pycharm)