# I can enter data to a program in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

Can I enter data to a program in PyCharm? For example, in this program:

```
import sys
 
def AB ():
     arch = sys.stdin.read (). splitlines ()
     for line in arch:
print "Hello world!"
AB ()
```

I would enter data in this way:

```
4 5
8 6
2 9
```

Comment: Its not really clear what youre asking

Comment: That program won't run, so isn't a good example. Have a look at e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26049559/pycharm-read-from-standard-input-in-debug-mode

Comment: I want to know is how to enter more data at once in PyCharm. thx

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that you haven't properly indented your print statement to be used in the for loop. Python doesn't use {} to distinguish blocks of code, but instead uses whitespace which forces the programmer to properly indent their code

```
def AB ():
   arch = sys.stdin.read().splitlines ()
   for line in arch:
print "Hello world!"
AB()
```

Should be

```
def AB ():
    arch = sys.stdin.read().splitlines ()
    for line in arch:
        print "Hello world!"
AB()
```

If you are trying to print 'Hello world!' for every line of input. If you wanted to print 'Hello world!' and then every line of input, then your code would be

```
def AB ():
    arch = sys.stdin.read().splitlines ()
    for line in arch:
        print line

print "Hello world!"
AB()
```