# using stdin in pycharm

Tags: python, stdin, pycharm

I have started to use pycharm and i can't seem to

in the command line i use to run the program in this way:

```
python parse_file.py < test.txt
```

when parse_file.py can be simple as :

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    print line
```

i cant find in the configuration where to do it i tried typeing something like `<test.txt` in the script parameters but no luck

I have looked at 
https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/run-debug-configuration-python.html

but no luck there also

Thanks

Comment: one way is to run the program from the terminal menu in pycharm. 
 $python prog1.py < input_1.txt No the best solution but is a way around.

Answer (score 4):

PyCharm's run configurations do not support standard input redirection. Please consider changing your script so that it reads its input from a file directly, and not through the standard input redirection.

Comment: For example, using `fileinput`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23942485/911945

Comment: In recent versions of pycharm (certainly 2020.2 professional), there is an option "Redirect Input From" under "Execution" in run configuration dialogues.

Answer (score 1):

There is solution, but it is not portable and you will have to adapt it to you OS. I describe it for Windows.

1. In File > Settings > Tools > External tools, create a new configuration, give it a name of your choice (example: *cmd input redirected*).
2. At the bottom of the form, for *Program* type `cmd.exe`. In *Parameters*, type `/c "$JDKPath$ parse_file.py < test.txt"` (**Double quotes are important**) and configure the *Working directory* to the folder where your files are stored.
3. Optionally, you can play with macros (buttons on the right) to replace some hard coded values by a variable equivalent, that will maybe help you to turn your external tool configuration into something reusable.

Now, you can right click on a file in your project, and select "External Tool > cmd input redirected".

The only annoying thing with that process is you will not be able to rerun the external tool with a shortcut while editing your code. To rerun, you have to set the focus on 'Run' tab, then use Ctrl + F5 (or simply click on the green triangle Rerun 'cmd input redirected'

Hope this help, regards

Comment: It won't let you debug the program too.