# Can read inputs but unable to execute script in Pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, program-entry-point

I recently started using Pycharm and I was trying to execute the starter code provided by one of my online classes from coursera. The code is to find gcd of two numbers:

```
import sys

def gcd_naive(a, b):
current_gcd = 1
for d in range(2, min(a, b) + 1):
    if a % d == 0 and b % d == 0:
        if d > current_gcd:
            current_gcd = d

return current_gcd

if __name__ == "__main__":
input = sys.stdin.read()
a, b = map(int, input.split())
print(gcd_naive(a, b))
```

I am only able to input the two numbers and the script doesn't execute after that at all and doesn't throw any errors either. I have attached the screenshot of my issue.[image]

I'd really appreciate a push in the right direction

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading from a file with sys.stdin in Pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21630403/reading-from-a-file-with-sys-stdin-in-pycharm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `sys.stdin.read()` to get user input, you have to end your input with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (in Windows) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> in Linux. However for some reason it doesn't work in PyCharm console/debug.

You can use the standard way of reading user input (using `input()` function), just change your main function to this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    a, b = map(int, input().split())
    print(gcd_naive(a, b))
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is reading from stdin. Seems like this doesn't seem to really work in PyCharm. This might be a duplicate question ([Reading from a file with sys.stdin in Pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21630403/reading-from-a-file-with-sys-stdin-in-pycharm)), ([using stdin in pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746755/using-stdin-in-pycharm)). Unless this is somehow for a grade I'd suggest ignoring the stdin aspect and instead of doing...

```
input = sys.stdin.read()
```

Just do...

```
input = "4 5"
```